# How to create confusion matrix in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I would need to create confusion matrix in java. Data is available in flats text files. I do have two text files. one file have actual data look like this

```
<PersonName>Amit</PersonName> <Address>XYZ</Address>
<PersonName>Sam</PersonName> <Address>St 123 UK </Address
```

in second file have predicted data look like this.

```
Amit: PersonName
Sam St: Address
```

Does anyone have any idea how to created the confusion matrix and calculate all false positive, false negative, true negative and true positive which is required to do that.

Comment: Confusion matrices tend to work well with binary data, which your data are not.

Answer (score 1):

So basically a confusion matrix is a `2D matrix` of size `n*n`. Where `n` stands for the number of possible categories to be predicted.

Now We need to maintain an indexed array of the n categories. For example:

`{Cat, Dog, Lion, Tiger}`

Suppose you have a list of predicted values and actual values:

```
Act       Pred
Cat       Cat
Cat       Dog
Dog       Lion
Lion      Lion
etc       etc
```

Now just assume that this array can be converted to a list of coordinates corresponding to the previous array:

```
A    P
0    0
0    1
etc  etc
```

Now the entries that are to be updated in the `2D array` are of the above index.

The code could look something like this:

```
    String[] a = new String[] {"airplanes", "butterfly", "flower", "grand_piano", "starfish", "watch"};
    Category = Arrays.asList(a);
    int [][] confMatrix = new int[6][6];
    for (Instance inst : predictedValues ) {
          String outLabel = inst.getPredictedLabel();
          String actualLabel = inst.getLabel();
          int outLabelIndex = Category.indexOf(outLabel);
          int actualLabelIndex =    Category.indexOf(actualLabel);
          confMatrix[actualLabelIndex][outLabelIndex] += 1;
    }
```